# Is my method for finding bases wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that you are given a set of vectors, say
$$
\textbf{u}_{1}, \textbf{u}_{2}, \textbf{u}_{3}, \dots,\textbf{u}_{n}
$$
And you're asked to find a basis for the given vectors.

It's clear that the vectors are linearly dependent, otherwise the question would have no point whatsoever. My method has been the following:

Let $V$ be the set generated by $\textbf{u}_{1}, \textbf{u}_{2}, \textbf{u}_{3}, \dots,\textbf{u}_{n}$, and $\textbf{v} \in V$ be any vector in $V$. Then, there exists a set of scalars $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}, \dots, c_{n}$ such that
$$
c_{1}\textbf{u}_{1}+ c_{2}\textbf{u}_{2}+ c_{3}\textbf{u}_{3}+ \dots+c_{n}\textbf{u}_{n} = \textbf{v}
$$
 Which can be summarized to the linear system
$$
U\textbf{c}=\textbf{v}
$$
Where U is the matrix whose columns are $\textbf{u}_{1}, \textbf{u}_{2}, \textbf{u}_{3}, \dots,\textbf{u}_{n}$, and $\textbf{c}$ is a column vector whose elements are $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}, \dots, c_{n}$.

Now, since any $\textbf{v}\in V$ is also an element of $Im(U)$, finding a basis for $V$ would be equivalent to finding a basis for $Im(U)$, and since $Im(U) = C_{U}$, where $C_{U}$ is the column space of $U$, then a basis for $C_{U}$ is also a basis for $V$.  From there on, it's as simple as doing some elementary column operations to find the linearly independent columns.

Now the actual question: is this wrong or incomplete? I've gone through quite a few exercises and, although i *do* get a linearly independent set of vectors that seems to generate the set, the answers I get are different from the answers I'm given. I know that bases aren't unique, but it puzzles me to get a different answer every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly it is to find a basis of the span of $\{u_1,\dots, u_n\}$ (and not a basis *for* the given vectors), in which case your method is correct.

If you are interested in finding a basis with vectors lying within $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ you may convert your matrix $U$ into row echelon form $U'$ by *row* transformations and obtain a basis of $C_U$ by selecting the original columns of $U$ corresponding to the pivot containing columns of $U'$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant: finding a basis of the span. Sorry if I wasn't clear about it. So it is correct... Thanks! :)